# How to fix embedded videos slow buffering speed on CentOS 7 server?

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, video-streaming

The video bufferings when embedded on other websites are so low on speed. It waits a lot of time to buffer the video. When they are playing on own server without embed its okay to buffer.

Tried installing mod streaming:

```
    $ wget http://h264.code-shop.com/download/apache_mod_h264_streaming-2.2.7.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf apache_mod_h264_streaming-2.2.7.tar.gz
$ cd mod_h264_streaming-2.2.7
$ ./configure
$ make
# make install
```

But it didn't take any affect.
Also changed the embed options but it didnt take any effect.

How to fix? Or how to tweak this problem?

Server: CentOS 7 , Webmin Panel Dedicated Server
Videos encoded with: mp4
Apache version 2.4.6 CentOS Linux 7.9.2009